# Tener un ejército ni el hdp - meaning of "ni"

Tags: diferencias-regionales, definiciones, vulgaridades

I have heard the following dialogue in the TV series Narcos:

- Sabías que Júlio Cesar invadió Gran Bretaña cuando tenía 44 años? Perdió el poder varias veces, pero siempre lo recuperó. Nunca se dejó derrotar.
- Pero ese gran marica tenía un ejército ni el hijo de puta, no?

What does "ni" mean here? Is it a Colombian regionalism?

Comment: I think "que" is omitted just before "ni": "tenía un ejército que ni el hijo de puta".

Comment: @Charo what would that mean?

Comment: Alan we need a link and a timestamp PLEASE.  Or make a little sound bite for us if it's behind a pay wall.

Comment: @aparente001 I watch this TV series on Netflix. It is not available for free in any legal site which I could link to here. If your concern is that I'm mishearing the sentence in hand, the Spanish subtitles available in the TV series confirm it.

Comment: A great answer came in, so we're good. // Lots of people do have netflix.  In future I think it's worthwhile to identify season, episode and time stamp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that context it's a Colombian regionalism used to express an exaggeration commonly used with vulgarity.

For example, someone wants to highlight the cold weather yesterday:
"ayer hacía un frío ni el *vulgar word here*"

or multiplying the vulgarity factor
"ayer hacía un frío ni el triple *vulgar word here*"

I can think of a similarity with expressions like "it's cold as a mtfk." 
Only use it with close friends.

edit:

More examples (common in Colombia - all vulgar):

---

**There was a huge line:**

> Había una fila ni la hijueputa

(In Colombia we say hijueputa instead of "hijo de puta")

---

**He had a really big knife**

> El tenía un cuchillo ni el hijueputa

**Complaining about yesterday's weather**

> Ayer hacía un calor ni el hijueputa

Comment: Can you give us a couple more examples?  I feel like I *almost* get it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, by the way there is no need to hide the vulgar words, this is a language site where all words are of interest.

Comment: @aparente001 I added a couple more examples.

Comment: Great answer! Small question: you wrote "había una fila ni **la** hijueputa." Is it true that the swearword ("hijueputa") must take the same gender as the noun it intensifies ("fila") ? What about number: would you then say "Tiene unos granos ni los hijos de puta"?

Comment: @wimi That's correct.